# angular smart dumb architectures forces me to have two variable for the same data

Tags: angular, rxjs

With angular if i have smart and dump components, if i have lets say an array in a smart component i need to make an observable out of it to make make the dump component read the input with an async pipe so that if i change the value of the array the detect change works and updated the dumb component. if i use just the array .

```
pieces = new ReplaySubject<{ item: Piece, index: number }[]>(1);
selectedPieces = new ReplaySubject<{ item: Piece, index: number }[]>(1);
piecesArray: { item: Piece, index: number }[];
selectedPiecesArray: { item: Piece, index: number }[] = [];
removePieces(pieces: { item: Piece, index: number }[]) {
        this.piecesArray = this.piecesArray.concat(...pieces);
        this.selectedPiecesArray = this.selectedPiecesArray.filter(p => pieces.indexOf(p) === -1);
        this.pieces.next(this.piecesArray.sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index));
        this.selectedPieces.next(this.selectedPiecesArray);
    }
```

what is the right way to handle this. should i use just observable and subscribe to it every time i need to operate on the value ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking for...

Comment: is it normal to have and array and  an observable that keeps the same value the array has just so that when i mutate the array the observable updates the dumb component with the new array data.

Comment: Well as you noted, you need to have the observable to allow proper change detection. You can use async pipe with @Input component binding so the child component will have just simple value, that is probably the best thing to do. Not sure if that is what you are referring in your question or if you mean just usage of async pipe in child component's template.

Comment: as you said with the async pipe the child component get simple value. but if i have an output from the child component to change the data of the array. should i subscribe in  the smart component get value alter it and call subject.next or should i have always an array in the smart and when  an out put get triggered from the child i alter the array and call subject.next with the array

Comment: then you need to pass also the observable/subject to it and call next on that... If you do not need to work with the value inside child controller, you can move the usage of async pipe to child template, but that's probably all you can do. You could also move the observable with the whole array so some shared service too.

Comment: I think what i try to say is that array are easy to use while with observable i have to subscribe every time i need to get the value to change it. is this alright or is there any better way to achieve it.

Comment: As I said, you could pass the value with async pipe in one property and also the observable in another property. Then you have the value to work with and the observable to pass new values. It might better to use shared service as I noted. That way you will use the service to mutate the array and also call `next` on the observable. Will add answer with example of that.

Comment: thanks i will use shared services it looks less messy that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I noted in comments, you could move all of the logic to shared service, that will hold both the array and the observable:

```
export class DataService {

  pieces = new ReplaySubject<{ item: Piece, index: number }[]>(1);
  selectedPieces = new ReplaySubject<{ item: Piece, index: number }[]>(1);
  piecesArray: { item: Piece, index: number }[];
  selectedPiecesArray: { item: Piece, index: number }[] = [];

  removePieces(pieces: { item: Piece, index: number }[]) {
    this.piecesArray = this.piecesArray.concat(...pieces);
    this.selectedPiecesArray = this.selectedPiecesArray.filter(p => pieces.indexOf(p) === -1);
    this.pieces.next(this.piecesArray.sort((a, b) => a.index - b.index));
    this.selectedPieces.next(this.selectedPiecesArray);
  }

}

export class MyComponent {

  constructor(public dataService: DataService) {}

}

<div>{{ dataService.pieces | async | json }}</div>
<div>{{ dataService.selectedPieces | async | json }}</div>

<a (click)="dataService.removePieces(...)">remove</a>
```